# Unable to Scan wifi Network with Reaver

Tags: wireless, network-manager, atheros

I'm trying to crack the WPS code using Reaver!
So far I can only get to the step where it is supposed to scan the networks...
What am I missing?

here is what I accomplished already: 
*root@xlr8nsys:~/Desktop# iwconfig*

eth0      no wireless extensions.

mon0      IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Tx-Power=14 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=14 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

*root@xlr8nsys:~/Desktop# airmon-ng start wlan0*

Found 2 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
14493   avahi-daemon
14494   avahi-daemon

Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Atheros     ath9k - [phy0]
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)

*root@xlr8nsys:~/Desktop# ifconfig mon0 down*

*root@xlr8nsys:~/Desktop# macchanger -a mon0*

Current MAC:   08:ed:b9:38:47:ea (Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.)
Permanent MAC: 08:ed:b9:38:47:ea (Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.)
New MAC:       00:14:11:38:47:ea (Deutschmann Automation GmbH & Co. KG)

*root@xlr8nsys:~/Desktop# ifconfig mon0 up*

*root@xlr8nsys:~/Desktop# wash -i mon0*

Wash v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Scan Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner

### BSSID                  Channel       RSSI       WPS Version       WPS Locked        ESSID

If I check the available networks from the interface directly, then I get this...

*root@xlr8nsys:~/Desktop# iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID*

ESSID:"PC WOW, Corp."
ESSID:"WOW Inn"
ESSID:"WOW Support"
ESSID:"WOW Media"
ESSID:"2WIRE554"

Answer (score 0):

Start from scratch. Reboot, then do the following:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
wash -i mon0
reaver -i mon0 -b BSSID -c CHANNELNUMBER -vv
```

Comment: It doesn't show any wifi network when issuing the command  "wash -i mon0"...